# Problem setting BlindCopyTo ItemValue in Lotus Notes

Tags: c#, email, lotus-notes

I got a certain issue regarding creating an eMail within Lotus Notes via COM.

There's not a general problem regarding creating the mail. The creation works fine, if no address is used which is associated with the Notes Server.

```
IList<string> receiverList = GetReceiver();
foreach ( var contact in receiverList )
{
    if ( receiverList.IndexOf( contact ) > 0 )
    {
        receiverBuilder.Append( "," );
    }
    receiverBuilder.Append( contact );
}
document.ReplaceItemValue( "BlindCopyTo", receiverBuilder.ToString() );
var item = document.CreateRichTextItem( "attachment" );
item.EmbedObject( EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", fileName, "attachment" );
document.Save( true, false, false );
```

Is there a possibility to escape the mail-address so that Notes ignores the internal directory and only uses the mail-address?

The Notes Document in Notes is displayed in a strange way (only one receiver is shown) and trying to send it, requests the local directory to verify entered addresses.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. But for all others facing this problem, I post the solution.

It is not neccessary to concatenate a string to set for the BlindCopyTo-Value. You can give the function an array of the addresses you want to mail to.

Like this:

```
IList<string> receiverList = GetReceiver();
document.ReplaceItemValue( "BlindCopyTo", receiverList.ToArray<string>() );
```